# "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" Using raw_input() in ArcMaps Python Console

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap

I am writing a python script to automate some ArcMaps data processing.  I am getting hung up at raw_input().  I am using raw_input to get input from a user.  A folder will be created with the folder name based on the user input.

I don't understand why this isn't working. I've viewed tutorials, read the manual, etc... and I still can't figure out why I am getting this error for raw_input().

I've managed to be able to get user to select files and directories suing the Tkinter toolkit should I look into using this toolkit to get text from a user prompt as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input` does not work in the Python window in ArcMap, plain and simple. Since the application is not a command line app there is no `sys.stdin` to read from.

I would recommend you instead write a geoprocessing script tool and use the dialog it provides for user input. Please refer to [this prior question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37304/python-scripts-that-run-inside-arcmap-vs-ones-that-run-outside) for more information.